# userId vs Meteor.userId vs Meteor.userId()

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm confused by the variable `userId` in this code:

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    // only allow posting if you are logged in
    return !! userId;
  }
});
```

The [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-userId) explain that `Meteor.userId` returns a function and `Meteor.userId()` returns a string, but I don't understand which of those is being referred to by `userId` above.

Answer (score 2):

Digging into the docs, it seems `userId` is just the default name given to the first argument of `allow()` and `deny()` methods. It could just as well be written like this:

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function(theUser, doc) {
    // only allow posting if you are logged in
    return !! theUser;
  }
});
```